# How do I calculate the distance between one atom to another in a cooper conductor?

Tags: particle-physics, electricity, material-science

Regarding the atomic model which  free electrons are moving from one atom to another, I want to estimate the distance between those atoms

Comment: Are you asking about Cooper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair or copper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper ?

Answer (score 1):

Electrons don't matter in this case - this is only about the nuclei. So, you know how many atoms a given mass of some material contains, right? That's simply the atomic weight and Avogadro's number. Now, instead of calculating absolute numbers for a given mass, you can use the density, which gives you number of atoms per unit volume. Take the cube root of that volume and you know the average distance between atoms in your material.